# Why did Super Friends change the Darkseid's "Boom Tube" to a "Stargate"?

Tags: dc, tv, adaptation-comparison, darkseid

As a kid, I started reading the original *New Gods* comics around the same time Darkseid first appeared on the *Super Friends* television cartoons.  One of the peculiar differences I noticed between the comics and the show (I could see why the roles of Kalibak and Desaad were different for the cartoon) was the seemingly unnecessary change of Darkseid's transportation method from Boom Tube to Stargate.

The name and appearance of the travel method was changed, from Kirby's original (as shown here from the first page of *Forever People* number 1)

[image: Boom Tube]

to this from the television show

[image: Stargate]

The [*Superfriends Wiki*](https://superfriends.fandom.com/wiki/Stargate) lists the two terms as synonymous, but their appearances are quite different, with the Stargate's [distinctive opening pattern](https://youtu.be/RaeYz7Ndq2k?t=95).  Other artists had portrayed the Boom Tubes differently, but they remained distinctively tube-like—for example, this frame by Rich Buckler from *Return of the New Gods* number 15

[image: Return of the New Gods]

So, is there a known reason why the change was made?  Was just a matter of artistic preference on the part of the television show creators?  Was the Stargate easier to animate?  Was the name "Boom Tube" considered problematic in some way?

Comment: Things that go "Boom" are annoying to parents.

Comment: Flash in the JLU show called it the "boob tube" while talking to Big Barda.

Comment: @Valorum or even worse... "SCRRREEEEEERREEEEEERRREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"

Comment: The show probably didn't license the rights to use the term "boom tube". The whole reason the show was called _Super Friends_ was they originally didn't license the term "Justice League".